# Make route work without specifying action name in URL. - MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following controller within my `MVC` project:

```
public class PressController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Press
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return File("../press/FFF_PRESS.zip", ".zip");
        }
    }
```

My routes

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

When I load the site my URL is as follows:

```
www.example.com
```

Which displays the home page correctly, when I click on the following `Action` `<li class="footer__navEl"><a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Press")'>PRESS</a></li>`

I would like the URL to be

```
www.example.com/press
```

and return the zip file.

However when I click this `Action` I get the following:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>   The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Yet when I specify

```
www.example.com/press/index
```

The .zip file is returned correctly.

Now I added the following to my routes.config:

```
routes.MapRoute("Press", "Press", new { controller = "Press", action = "Index" });
```

I still get the same error mentioned above, can someone shed some light into what I might be missing to get this to perform correctly?

Comment: Have you setting `MapRoute` in right order? `[domain]/Press` will request to show `Press` directory content, which by default is disabled in IIS. The route order or format should be adjusted so that `Press` controller evaluated first before default one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

The error indicates you have a *physical* directory on your web server named `press`. What is happening is that the web server is returning the directory instead of passing the request on to MVC. The default setting in IIS is not to list the directory's contents, hence the error.

You need to either delete the `press` directory (recommended), or reconfigure IIS to run the MVC module instead of the directory by using the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`, which [has some caveats](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/oct/25/caveats-with-the-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-in-iis-78).

This isn't a routing problem at all - it is a webserver configuration problem.